# Bluetooth headphones reconnect as headset in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, headphones, headset

I can connect bluetooth headphones to my windows 10 pc with no problem but when they reconnect for some reason they connect as a headset not headphones. If I delete and repair I get headphones back

This is the case with every pair of BT Headphones I try on the PC

I'm using an ASUS USB BT-4000 for the BT on my computer.

If I look at the Bluetooth device dialog while it is reconnecting I get Both a headphone & Headset icon appearing for a second then the headphone one vanishes.

I've tried reinstalling the BT-4000 driver but it made no difference.

Any ideas. It's driving me nuts having to repair the headpones several times a day!